# How do we get autocomplete to suggest Mongoose model properties in WebStorm?

Tags: express, mongoose, webstorm

I have a model Tank in tank.js

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

I export it through the index file together with other models.

In the route js file, I then find a tank, then try to change the name.

```
Tank.findById(1).then(tank =>{ tank.name = 'foo' });
```

Or try to create a new instance of tank.

```
let tankA = new Tank();
tankA.name = 'bar';
```

But the autocomplete does not suggest name property of Tank. Is there any way to get WebStorm or other IDEs to suggest the properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolving model properties requires providing special support for Mongoose. Right now, WebStorm knows nothing about Mongoose `module(name, schema)` function, `methods` and `statics` objects, etc., so no completion is available.
Please vote for [WEB-22317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22317) to be notified on any progress with this feature